# Node Express 404 even when routes are defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I believe this will be hard to trouble shoot without me giving more information.

But, I have the following set up in a small modular setup:

**//index.js aka the server**

```
...
// set views path, template engine and default layout
app.set('views', './app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var routes = require('./app/routes')
....
```

**//routes.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();

// Include the controllers
var home = require('../controllers/home');

// GET home page
router.get('/', home.home);
router.get('/home', home.home);

module.exports = router;
```

**//controllers/home.js**

```
module.exports = {
    home: function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Home Page'
        });
    }
};
```

Then navigating to `/` returns:

```
Cannot GET /
```

I started node as of 2 hours ago... so... I suck basically :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your problem is you never connect your index.js `app` express instance to the router you define in routes.js. In index.js, append a line after you require routes:

```
app.use(routes);
```

Now the main express instance will include the routes defined in routes.js when routing requests through the middleware stack and you should be up and running.

Comment: Umm simple things :O I blame it being 3am :) Thanks